# How to show Map View in a particular selected View using Map Box

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiview, mapbox

I have a `UIView` of Size `(height = 213 , Width = 375)`, i just wanted to display map inside this `UIView` only. 
I have written the code for displaying Map using **Mapbox**, but it shows the map inside full screen. the code is shown below

```
    let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: 
    MGLStyle.satelliteStreetsStyleURL())
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.74699, longitude: -73.98742), zoomLevel: 9, animated: false)
    view.addSubview(mapView)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created an outlet for that UIView named mapView and then changed the following things in the code:

```
let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: mapView.bounds, styleURL: 
MGLStyle.satelliteStreetsStyleURL())
mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.74699, longitude: -73.98742), zoomLevel: 9, animated: false)
view.addSubview(mapView)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the frame for your map view is being set to the size of the root view controller. `frame` takes a CGRect. You can change the size of your map view by adjusting the values in that CGRect.

```
let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 213), styleURL: 
MGLStyle.satelliteStreetsStyleURL())
mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.74699, longitude: -73.98742), zoomLevel: 9, animated: false)
view.addSubview(mapView)
```

Comment: Instead of giving width and height, we have to give the frame bounds of that view only.